# Добавление новых метаданных в REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest

Объясняю проблему. С помощью плагина WP REST API Controller обнаружил в пользовательском типе следующие метаданные:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Включенные из них - необходимые для меня метаданные. Этот пользовательский тип строится в другом плагине. Далее. Мне необходимо добавить дополнительные метаданные. В интернете прочитал, что для добавления полей используется функция **add_post_meta()**. Произведя поиск упоминаний этой функции в коде, обнаружил, что в одном месте действительно происходит нечто связанное с метаданными указанного выше пользовательского типа. Вот пример в коде для одного из поля:

```
    add_post_meta($order['id'], "booking_order_pond_id", $id, true);
```

И это единственное упоминание с подобным названием (booking_order_pond_id) во всём коде плагина. Попробовав повторить, добавил строкой ниже похожую запись:

```
    add_post_meta($order['id'], "booking_order_place_id", $place_id, true);
```

После сохранения, посмотрел в список, который изображён на картинке и не обнаружил новый Meta Key. Возможно, я использую не ту функцию или делаю это как-то не так. Вопрос следующий: как это делается на самом деле?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того чтобы значение мета поля отобразилось в rest api его нужно зарегистрировать и передать в аргументах `'show_in_rest' => true` , например вот так

```
register_post_meta( 
    'page',    // тип поста к которому нужно добавить мета поле, можно указать пустую строку тогда поле будет добавлено для всех типов постов
    'booking_order_place_id', 
    [
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    ]
);
```

Подробнее можно ознакомиться по ссылке https://wp-kama.ru/function/register_post_meta

Answer (score 0):

Это называется [произвольные поля](https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F) (ПП).

Функции для работы с ПП:
[add_post_meta()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/add_post_meta)
[update_post_meta()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/update_post_meta)
[delete_post_meta()](https://wp-kama.ru/function/delete_post_meta)